# Question regarding temperature as a property of a system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

This is probably silly question but I got stuck while reading “Lectures on Theoretical Physics-Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics” by Sommerfeld.
In the first chapter it says :

> Temperature is a property or parameter of state. It is independent of the previous history of the body and is defined solely by its instantaneous state. It is associated with the behavior of the body at the instant under consideration, or else, it is measured with reference to the instantaneous indication of a thermometer.

Later it is shown that the integral of dT for any closed path is zero. Thus T is a property.

Then after that it is stated that since work done isn’t always an exact differential, we cannot say that a property W exists. Same goes for quantity dQ because there is no characteristic heat content which would simply describe the instantaneous state of the system.

My question is, say, if I have water at 10 degree Celsius and I apply heat to it such that it becomes water at say, 20 degree Celsius, then at that instant, it has that temperature because I applied the heat. **So why it is that temperature is a property independent of the previous history of the body? The temperature of any system at any instant is a result of some process it underwent so how can it be independent of the history?**

Comment: Because you could also have *cooled* the water from 50 C down to 20 C?

Comment: It is a *property* because it does not matter how it has got to 20C it *is* 20C. The amount of work or heat transfer needed has no bearing on it being 20C, it is now 20C. The amount of work or heat it has taken to get 20C depends on the route (history), that is why those (heat, work) are not system properties.